# How do I "cwd" in a swift shell script?

Tags: swift, macos, shell

I'm playing around with Swift as a shell language. How do I change the working directory of the process?

I know there is a `changeCurrentDirectoryPath(_:)`. How to set that up and use the `FileManager`?

Comment: Is https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager/1412020-changecurrentdirectorypath what you are looking for?

Comment: I saw that. I should have put in more detail in the question. I should be asking how to set that up and use it with the FIlemanager.

Comment: `FileManager.default.changeCurrentDirectoryPath("/path/to/the/new/working/directory")`

Comment: Thanks! How do I mark a comment as the solution?

Comment: Comments can not be “accepted as the solution,” only answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`changeCurrentDirectoryPath(_:)` is an *instance method* of the `FileManager` class. It can be called on the shared file manager object for the process (the “default” instance). Don't forget to check the return value for success or failure:

```
if !FileManager.default.changeCurrentDirectoryPath("/path/to/new/wd") {
    // Changing the working directory failed.
}
```